# Why is sequential Stern-Gerlach experiment a complete surprise?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin

In page 5 of his Modern QM , Sakurai block $S_z-$ from first S-G experiment and sends $S_z+$ atoms to next S-G experimen in $x$-direction. Then sends the result of second experiment to third S-G experiment in $z-$direction and gain some atoms with $S_z-$ spin. He says this is a complete surprise. But why? In second experiment we simply send $S_z+$ atom to a strong magnetic field in $x-$direction and so make their magnetic moments vector to precess around $x-$axis and so they obtain component in $z-$ direction. Where is the surprise?

Comment: It is only "a surprise" if we try to make a classical model for spins, which is probably what he means. The quantum mechanical calculation does give the experimentally observed result. I don't have the book, though, so I can't comment on his particular language and the way the author makes this argument in detail.

Comment: Classical models break down in discreteness of result. But about above sequential experiments by now I think there is simple classical explanation (by classical magnetic mment vector) as I said in question. @FlatterMann

Comment: It's the discreteness of the result, but also the fact that we can not make the measurement outcome independent of the measurement system. In classical mechanics "the measurement result" is thought of as an inherent physical property of the system under measurement alone. In QM the outcome is always a function of the combination of the system under measurement and the measurement system. In a SG experiment this is observed as an (unavoidable) exchange of angular momentum (and energy) between the beam and the SG's magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

It's like with magic tricks: If you know the mechanism you are no longer surprised. However, if somebody first shows you a red ball and then after some supposedly irrelevant manipulations shows you that now the ball is blue, you are caught by surprise. I reckon the fact that Stern and Gerlach were nominated several times to obtain the Nobel price is a good indicator how surprised people were at that time.

And maybe one more thing: After the third magnet we get two groups. This contradicts classical physics, because the input parameters were perfectly defined (e.g. spin points up in z-direction and up in x-direction). Why do we obtain two groups and not a single well-defined state? Is this not surprising?